# Why body starts moving when force is applied?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

The recent question by m.buettner regarding self-inductance and its resistance to EMF [Faraday's law - does the induced current's magnetic field affect the change in flux?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62721/), recalled me the great question that I always wanted to ask. The 3rd law of Newton says [*To every action there is always an equal and opposite reaction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_3rd_Law). This immediately means that action is exactly balanced by reaction force and, because of zero net force, no speed increase should be observed. How do you explain why our concerns with m.buettner are unfounded?

Comment: This is a common question.  See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63306/clarification-regarding-newtons-third-law-of-motion-and-why-movement-is-possibl and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45653/with-newtons-third-law-why-are-things-capable-of-moving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each action of body A on body B, there is a reaction of *body B* on *body A*. The two forces do not apply on the same body and thus won't cancel each other when looking at the movement of body B only.